# Similar parsing programs: why does one work, while the other does not?

Tags: php, parsing, logic, fgets, string-parsing

This works:

```
<?php
  //compare1.php
  //**CLASS AND OBJECT
  class Entry
  {
    private $s_ids;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->s_ids      = array();
    }

    public function AddS_id($s_id)
    {
      $this->s_id[] = $s_id;
    }

    public function SetS_ids($s_ids)
    {
      $this->s_ids[] = $s_ids;
    }

    public function GetS_id($i)
    {
      if ($i > count($s_ids))
        throw new Exception('Out of bounds.');
      return $this->s_ids[$i];
    }

    public function GetS_ids()
    {
      return $this->s_ids;
    }
  }


  //EXTRACTION FUNCTION
  function extractS_ids($line)
  {
    $matches;
    preg_match('/^S_id:\s+(.*)\s+$/', $line, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
  }


  //LINE CHECKS
  function isStart($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^Start.*$/', $line);
  }

  function isS_id($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^S_id:\s+(.*)$/', $line);
  }

  function isEnd($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^End.*$/', $line);
  }


  //VARIABLE DECLARATION
  $fName = 'sample1.txt';
  $fh    = fopen($fName, 'r');
  $line;
  $entry;
  $entrys = array();


  //PARSE OPERATION
  if ($fh === FALSE)
    die ('Failed to open file.');

  while (($line = fGets($fh)) !== FALSE)
  {
    if (isStart($line)){
      $entry = new Entry();
    }
    if (isS_id($line)){
      $entry->SetS_ids(extractS_ids($line));
    }
    if (isEnd($line)){
      $entrys[] = $entry;
    }
  }


  //ARRAY RETRIEVAL
  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($entrys);
  echo "</pre>";
  fclose($fh);

?>
```

With this sample file:

```
Start
S_id:      0611147
S_id:      0651134
End

Start
S_id:      0611125
S_id:      0651125
End
```

This does not work:

```
<?php
  //compare2.php
  //CLASS AND OBJECT
  class Entry
    {
      private $titles; 

      public function __construct()
      {
        $this->titles = array();
      }

      public function AddType($title)
      {
        $this->titles[] = $title;
      }

      public function SetTitles($titles)
      {
        $this->titles[] = $titles;
      }

      public function GetTitle($i)
      {
        if ($i > count($titles))
          throw new Exception('Out of bounds.');
        return $this->titles[$i];
      }

      public function GetTitles()
      {
        return $this->titles;
      }
    }

  //EXTRACTION FUNCTION
  function extractTitles($line)
  {
    $matches;
    preg_match('/^<title>(.*)<\/title>.*$/', $line, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
  }

  //LINE CHECK FUNCTION
  function isStart_entry($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^<title>.*$/', $line);
  }

  function isTitle($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^<title>.*<\/title>.*$/', $line);
  }

  function isClose_entry($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^<\/list>.*$/', $line);
  }


  //DECLARATIONS
  $fName = 'sample2.txt';
  $fh    = fopen($fName, 'r');
  $line;
  $entry;
  $entrys = array();


  //PARSE OPERATION
  if ($fh === FALSE)
    die ('Failed to open file.');

  while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== FALSE)
  {
    if (isStart_entry($line)){
      $entry = new Entry();
    }
    if (isTitle($line)){
      $entry->SetTitles(extractTitles($line));
    }
    if (isClose_entry($line)){
      $entrys[] = $entry;
    }
  }

  // Dump the results.
  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($entrys);
  echo "</pre>";

  // Close the file.
  fclose($fh);
?>
```

With this sample file:

```
<list>
<title>Coco</title>
<title>Cafe Milk Tea</title>
</list>
<list>
<title>Strong Off</title>
<title>5% Grapefruit</title>
</list>
```

The logic seems the same.  I checked the plurals, and I checked the preg match functions.  Everything in `compare1.php` seems to parallel `compare2.php`, but look at the differences in the outputs:

Output1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Entry Object
        (
            [s_ids:Entry:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0611147
                    [1] => 0651134
                )

        )

    [1] => Entry Object
        (
            [s_ids:Entry:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0611125
                    [1] => 0651125
                )

        )
```

Output 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Entry Object
        (
            [titles:Entry:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cafe Milk Tea
                )

        )

    [1] => Entry Object
        (
            [titles:Entry:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5% Grapefruit
                )

        )

)


)
```

How can the files be pretty much exactly the same, and yet the latter of the two returns a different kind of result?  Shouldn't `[0] => 5% Grapefruit` be `[0] => Strong off; [1] => 5% Grapefruit`?  And `[0] => Cafe Milk Tea` be `[0] => Coco; [1] => Cafe Milk Tea`?

Comment: Take a pen, paper and execute manually each of these code line by line

Comment: @zerkms I've done that six or seven times, now.  Everything looks exactly the same.  I don't see any differences.  I'll re-do it right now two or three more times, though.  I'm looking at the code in split-view, writing this down, right now, as per your request.

Comment: "Everything looks exactly the same. I don't see any differences" --- don't compare code, but compare intermediate results

Comment: @zerkms, I understand.  Thank you.  I had not done that, yet.  Very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isStart_entry` function is looking for `<title>` instead of `<list>`. It should be coded like this:

```
function isStart_entry($line)
{
  return preg_match('/^<list>.*$/', $line);
}
```

Comment: Yes, dude.  I went through it two more times, and I didn't see that.  I just found an 's' in the wrong place.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know why `\s+$` works and `.*$` does not work in my extraction functions?  I only get the second `S_id` or `<title>` when I use `.*$`, instead of the full array.  This is a problem with `html attributes` because `.*$` is used after the closing quote, `"{1,}` that completes the attribute, and `\s+` cannot be used.  Is it possible that `.*` is also matching `\r\n`, and is there a way to make it not do that like `[^\r\n]`?